# Polish and polish sort of words

Tags: word-usage, homophones

A homophone is a word that is pronounced the same as another word but differs in meaning. Is there a name for two words with the same spelling but with different meanings? For example: Polish (someone from Poland) and polish (rubbing something to make it shiny).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [graphic](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Homonyms-Homophones-and-Homographs-for-ESL-Students) showing the various relationships:

[image]

What you're asking about is a ***homograph***

The linked website goes on to say about them:

> Homographs are words that are spelled the same but have different meanings. These words may have the same or different sound. For example, the word, a tear in her eye, and to tear down the house are homographs. In this situation, tear as a noun and tear as a verb are spelled the same, pronounced differently, and have different meanings. Citing another example, a birthday present and to present my friend to my mother indicate the use of present as both a noun and a verb. The pronunciations are different because when present is used as a noun, the stress is on the first syllable of the word. When present is used as a verb, the stress is on the second syllable of the word. Students should be taught the rule that for two syllable words used as both nouns and verbs, the stress is on the first syllable for nouns and on the second syllable for verbs.

Also as @RegDwigнt points out:

A [***capitonym***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym)  is a special type of homograph that is formed just by changing the capitalization of the word.

Comment: It's a homograph, yes, but this particular type of homographs has the more specific name [capitonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym).

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Wow.  I didn’t know that one.  Thanks.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yeah, it is addressed in that post linked as dupe, but it is a lot of TLDR to get to it.